# How to support chained Element queries with Twig tags

Tags: elementtype, elementquery

The `craft` variable allows you to chain queries for your Elements. For example, you can query the first Entry in a section with either of the following syntaxes:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries({ section: 'news' }).one() %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').one() %}
```

How do we support both of these syntaxes in a Custom Element type?

The Craft Variable defines the `entries` tag like so:

```
public function entries(array $criteria = []): EntryQuery
{
  $query = Entry::find();
  Craft::configure($query, $criteria);

  return $query;
}
```

And, within the `EntryQuery` class, a public `section` method is defined:

```
public function section($value)
{
  if ($value instanceof Section) {
    $this->structureId = ($value->structureId ?: false);
    $this->sectionId = $value->id;
  } else if ($value !== null) {
    $this->sectionId = (new Query())
      ->select(['id'])
      ->from([Table::SECTIONS])
      ->where(Db::parseParam('handle', $value))
      ->column();
  } else {
    $this->sectionId = null;
  }

  return $this;
}
```

And there appears to be a `__set` method on the EntryQuery that also references the `section` method:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
  switch ($name) {
    case 'section':
      $this->section($value);
      break;
    case 'type':
      $this->type($value);
      break;
    case 'authorGroup':
      $this->authorGroup($value);
      break;
    default:
      parent::__set($name, $value);
  }
}
```

I've experimented with all of those and still only seem to be able to support the first syntax:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries({ section: 'news' }).one() %}
```

But can't seem to find a way to support the second syntax:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').one() %}
```

What am I overlooking? What does a custom Element Type need to add to support the chained syntax for an Element Query via a Twig variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the instance in every single `set` call. As you noticed correctly the last line in **every** function that changes properties of your query is `return $this` which allows you to chain another function after the call. Simple as that.

Always return the query until you execute it with `all()` or another function like that is enough

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Not sure why things were not working originally. It may have had something to do with where I was killing the script to test in the variable class and how the chained methods get processed. Seems as if it's all working now.